# installation of rails in ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation

Edit:

`rails -v` is not working. When I am running `~$ rails new`, the db folder is not having any file within it. `~$ rails g scaffold project`; everything is created but no migrate folder is created.

Please help me to solve the situation. Even it is showing error in `gem install bundle:

> ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteSourceException) HTTP
>   Response 302 fetching gems.rubyforge.org/yaml

```
~$ rails -v
getopt: invalid option -- 'v'
Terminating...
~$RAILS(1)                                                              RAILS(1)

NAME
       rails - Ruby on Rails deployment script

SYNOPSIS
       rails [options] destination(s)...

OPTIONS
       -d, --no-docs
              Deploys rails without any documentation.

       -C, --copy
              Deploys rails by copying instead of linking vendor libraries.

       -F, --force-overwrite
              Overwrites all previously deployed files, if any.

       -D, --database
              Specify  the  database  to  be used. Supported values are mysql,
              oracle, postgresql, sqlite3, frontbase and ibm_db

       -I, --internal
 Manual page rails(1) line 1/42 57%
```

Comment: when i am running ~$ rails new

the db folder is not having any file within it

~$ rails g scaffold project

everything is created but no migrate folder is created

please help me to solve the situation

Comment: even it is showing error in  gem install bundle
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteSourceException)
    HTTP Response 302 fetching http://gems.rubyforge.org/yaml

Comment: http://community.activestate.com/faq/running-rails-debian

Comment: You should try using Google sometimes. It's this really great website that allows you to search for things on the internet.

Comment: even this is not solving my problem

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to http://rubygems.org
2. Download the RubyGems .zip or .tar.gz file
3. Unzip or untar the file you just downloaded
4. Change directories to the directory created by unzipping or untarring
5. Run ‘ruby setup.rb’

Answer (score 0):

You need to update RubyGems, here are instructions: http://rubygems.org/pages/download#formats